# How to add value for each specific key in python dictionary? (do not update another key)

Tags: python, dictionary

In my case, I have a dictionary like this

```
dic_ = {'btcusd': [-1.0, -1.0],
        'usdjpy': [-1.0, -1.0]}
```

For example, I would like to update the key 'usdjpy', I using this code

```
dic_['usdjpy'].append(1)
```

However, It updates all other keys in this dictionary and gives the result like

```
{'btcusd': [-1.0, -1.0, 1],
 'usdjpy': [-1.0, -1.0, 1]}
```

So how to solve this problem?

My desire result is as below

```
{'btcusd': [-1.0, -1.0],
 'usdjpy': [-1.0, -1.0, 1]}
```

Comment: How have you created the dict?

Comment: Due to I need to generate many dicts which have same format so I create the function by dict_ = dict(zip(symbol_list, [list()]*len(symbol_list)))

Comment: Probably dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of this problem comes from the way I define the dictionary. Like @yatu comment under my post.
For example, If I generate the dictionary like this

```
symbol_list = ['a', 'b, 'c', 'd']
dict_ = dict(zip(symbol_list, [list()]*len(symbol_list)))
```

Then append using normal `.append()` method. It will append for all value-list in this `dict_`

But if creating the `dict_` in another way like

```
symbol_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
dict_ = {}
for x in range(0, len(symbol_list)):
    dict_[symbol_list[x]]= list()
```

then the `append()` method will work as desired

The reason is answered in detail in this post: [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is during the initialization of your dictionary. Do check, the id's for both the list are same. i.e. the memory in which both the list are is same.

```
> id('btcusd') == id('usdjpy')
True
```

To replicate this issue, Here I have initialized the an list for a,b

```
> list = ['a','b']
> dic_ = dict.fromkeys(list, [-1.0,1.0])
> dic_['a'] is dic['b']
True
```

You can use list comprehension for sorting the issue

```
> dic_ = {key: [-1.0,1.0] for key in list}
> dic_['a'] is dic_['b']
False
```

Just in your case, the issue is your initialization:

```
dict_ = dict(zip(symbol_list, [list()]*len(symbol_list)))
```

Just for a demo on `[list()]*len(symbol_list)`,

```
> l = [['a']]*3
[['a'], ['a'], ['a']]
> for i in l:
>    print(id(i), end=' : ')
139970284317824 : 139970284317824 : 139970284317824
```

Answer (score 0):

there must be something else that you're doing to get this result.
I tried it and it works just fine

```
dic_ = {'btcusd': [-1.0, -1.0],
        'usdjpy': [-1.0, -1.0]}
dic_['usdjpy'].append(1)
print(dic_)
```

output

```
{'btcusd': [-1.0, -1.0], 'usdjpy': [-1.0, -1.0, 1]}
```